# Redirect url to www in reactjs nextjs as a server side 301

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js, server-side, http-status-code-301

I have some trouble to route my web site to same redirect but with www server side. For example if a user browses my web site example.com , i should redirect it to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I found nextjs redirect and did something like in next.config.js as follow.

```
module.exports = {
 async redirects() {
return [
   {
     source: '/',
     destination: 'https://www.example.com/',
     statusCode: 301
   },
   ]
  },
}
```

but when i publish this code, i got too many redirect error as a normally but i cant found a solution to put a condition if the source path  does not start with www then start this redirect rules. Anyone helps me how to do this ? I dont need client side redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think nextjs provides such an opportunity because it targets the base url that comes after your domain name. In my opinion, the best way to achieve this is to use a `.htaccess` file. You can just pass this code into it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also if you want to redirect from http to https add this code below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: hello , thanks to answer but i didint understand excatly.  i have a react project and should i add a file name .htaccess in root directory and write the commands that is above in the file ?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! Note, it should work on the apache web-server

Comment: my react project in linux app service base on nginx web server. hope that it works on it. i'll try it . If it helps, i approved your answer. thank you

Comment: Thank you, you can write, if you have any problems, I will try to help

Comment: Also this [article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirect-nginx-non-www-to-www-domain-over-ssl/) can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-redirect this link is very useful for both client and server side.

```
import redirect from 'nextjs-redirect'
export default redirect('https://paypal.me')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily handle permanent redirection from non-www to www in nextjs using the below-mentioned code.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { req, res } = context;
    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) === null) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
    location: "https://"+ "www."+ req.headers.host + req.url,
    });
    res.end();
    } 
    return { props: {} };
    };
```